# Blender 2.8 Front and Back Background Images

Tags: image

I have two reference images, one for the front and one for the back. I want the images to be slightly transparent, but then I will see both images which will be confusing. How would I make it so that an image only shows up when I'm in front view, and the other only shows up when I'm in the back view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blender 2.8, background is an object.

1. select one of viewpoint (if you skip this step, the background is always visible regardless of viewport angle)
2. type Shift-A, and select Image → Background
3. select an image file

Then, you'll get an object with image. The object has settings for *transparency* and *side*, which you want.

So, add two background objects that way, and set the side to *Front* for one, and to *Back* for the other.

[image]